# Query the DB that includes two tables

Tags: mysql

I am totally new to MYSQL DB. I am trying to query a table that includes another tables two fields.

There are two tables

1. ORDER DETAILS
2. CUSTOMER DETAILS

Both are linked using customer_id

I want to get all the data from ORDER DETAILS that has a particular field in ORDER DETAILS plus I want to add it's customer name and employee id with it from customer details.

How is this possible? (I know the basic SELECT * but I don't know anything on JOIN etc please help!

ie. I want all the fields from Order_details + two fields from Customer_details where store_id = "something" (this field is in order_details) - As store_id is not there in customer_details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion, this was the final answer:

```
SELECT order_id,order_details.customer_id,order_name,store_id,customer_name,emp_id from order_details,customer_details where order_details.customer_id=customer_details.customer_id and store_id='12345'
```

Comment: I want all the fields from Order_details + two fields from Customer_details where storedetails = something from order_details

Comment: you cant do *,field1,field2.  you will need to spell out the fields you want.

Comment: Got it but I want to get all details from order_details and two fields from customer_details where store_details (from order details)? I can't do this with your query.

Comment: I dont see a store_details table... but i assume it has a matching id from order_details?  see answer edit

Comment: Sorry for confussion: It is not store_details but store_id which is a field inside order_details.

Comment: so order_details.store_id also appears in customer_details table?

Comment: No.. It is only in Order_details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128673/discussion-between-bart2puck-and-sanjana-nair).

Comment: I am getting only 30 whereas totally 244 records are there.. Do you know anything what could be wrong here?

Comment: confirm each record's customer_ids match on both tables. confirm store_id matches

Comment: without seeing the data in your tables. i cant do much.  how do you know there are 244?

Comment: because I do select * from order_details where store_id = "0002" - I get 244 records.